# Using vectors in C++ program is not printing anything

Tags: c++

I have written a C++ program to find fibonacci numbers. It's running successfully but is not printing anything.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int n = 5;

vector<int> fib;

fib[0] = 0;
fib[1] = 1;


for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
}

cout<<fib[n];
}
```

If I do the same thing using array instead of vector it prints successfully.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int n = 5;

int fib[10];

fib[0] = 0;
fib[1] = 1;


for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
}

cout<<fib[n];
}
```

I have tested this on sublime text and onlinegdb.

Comment: C++ vectors are not like javascript vectors, you need to give them a size via either the constructor `std::vector<int> fib(10);` or via `.resize(10)` otherwise you're incurring undefined behavior by accessing elements that don't exist (something that would be caught by using `.at()` instead of subscript

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using that tells you to use the completely non-standard and undocumented `bits/stdc++.h` header file? You should really throw it away and get a better C++ textbook, that teaches standard C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int fib[10];
```

This creates an array of 10 integers.

```
vector<int> fib;
```

This creates a vector of size 0, with 0 integers.

For these two snippets to match, you need to initialize the vector with 10 integers like the array. So:

```
vector<int> fib(10);
```

---

#### Some notes on vectors

One of the big differences between `std::vector` and primitive arrays is that `std::vector` is resizable! So while initializing the vector with 10 ints like above will work, you could also add them on the fly using [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or by calling [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Likewise, `std::vector` has a [`.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function for access. It's marginally slower than the subscript operator (`[]`), so I would not suggest using it in production-level code. But while you're learning, I would strongly suggest using `.at()`, as it will do bounds checking for you. So this program would've told you you were trying to access locations in the vector that don't exist--instead of just running with Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `.resize(10)` would work as well.

Comment: @Mgetz so would `push_back()`, etc. I chose the simplest solution to get the two to match.

Comment: Not to forget that `push_back` should be combined with `reserve` – but these two together are most efficient in most cases...

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you wrote :

```
vector<int> fib;//creates an empty vector that is a vector of size 0

fib[0] = 0; //UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
fib[1] = 1; //UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
```

In the above code snippet, you created an **empty** `std::vector`. That is a vector of size `0`.

Next when you wrote `fib[0] = 0;` you're trying access the first element of the vector. That is, the element at index `0`. But note that there is **no element** inside the vector and so you have **undefined behavior** in your program.

Similarly when you wrote `fib[1] = 1;`, you're trying to access the second element of the vector. But since there is no element inside the vector, this again leads to undefined behavior.

To **solve** this you can create a vector of some size(say 10) and then access its elements as shown below:

```
vector<int> fib(10);//create vector of size 10

fib[0] = 0;//OK NOW
fib[1] = 1;//OK NOW
```

Since you're using *indices* to access the elements of the vector, i have not suggested `push_back`. `std::vector::push_back` is a member function that can be used to add an element into the vector.